# Client Server Communication socket programming in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

The code below is creating a server to communicate with clients.This code works fine over HTTP but does not work correctly in HTTPS. Suggest a method or network function need to be included to work fine over ssl.

```
#define SOCKET_OK 0

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
                               LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShow)
{
WORD sockVer;
WSADATA wsaData;
int retVal;

sockVer = MAKEWORD(2,2);

WSAStartup(sockVer, &wsaData);

/// Creating socket
SOCKET servSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if(servSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to create socket()", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
    WSACleanup();
    return SOCKET_ERROR;
}

/// Filling in sockaddr_in struct 

SOCKADDR_IN sin;
sin.sin_family = PF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(1111);
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

retVal = bind(servSock, (LPSOCKADDR)&sin, sizeof(sin));
if(retVal == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to bind", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
    WSACleanup();
    return SOCKET_ERROR;
}

/// Trying to listen socket
retVal = listen(servSock, 10);
if(retVal == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
       MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to listen()", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
    WSACleanup();
    return SOCKET_ERROR;
}

/// Waiting for a client
SOCKET clientSock;

clientSock = accept(servSock, NULL, NULL);

if(clientSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to accept()", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
    WSACleanup();
    return SOCKET_ERROR;
}

char szReq[8]; 
retVal = recv(clientSock, szReq, 8, 0);

if(retVal == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to recv()", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
    return SOCKET_ERROR;
}

MessageBox(NULL, szReq, "Got the request from client", MB_OK);


char *szResp = "Response";

MessageBox(NULL, szResp, "Sending response from server", MB_OK);
retVal = send(clientSock, szResp, strlen(szResp), 0);

if(retVal == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to send()", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
    return SOCKET_ERROR;
}

/// Closing socket
closesocket(clientSock);
closesocket(servSock);

WSACleanup();

return SOCKET_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket is a lower-level protocol than http and https - http and https run on top of it. Your apprach using socket should work with https - but you are going to get the raw, encrypted data - that is probably not what you want.

I suggest you look into using higher-level classes - like WinInet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w2azyt6.aspx